# makefile error when adding include path

Tags: header, makefile, g++, linker-errors

i have a very strange error within my makefile: if I pass an incorrect path to the boost include folder the following builds and i get a .o file. However when i pass the correct path i get the following error:

> /src/third-party/build/boost_1_49_0/include/boost/container/map.hpp:147:1:
>   error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type
>   ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE’  make: *** [Bidding.o] Error 1

The makefile is below

```
CC=g++
TPLOC=/home/zil/RTB2/0.1/src/third-party/build
COMMON=/home/zil/RTB2/0.1/src/common
SRC_HEAD=/home/zil/RTB2/0.1

all:  Bidder.o main.o main

Bidder.o: Bidder.cpp
       $(CC) -g -fPIC -c Bids.cpp -I$(TPLOC)/boost_1_49_0/include -I.

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -g -fPIC -c main.cpp -I$(TPLOC)/boost_1_49_0/include -I$(COMMON) -I$(TPLOC)/libzdb/include/zdb -I$(TPLOC)/apache/include

main: main.o
    $(CC) -fPIC main.o -o /home/zil/sandbox9/$@ -lbk -lrtbshm -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lapr-1 -lrt -lpthread -lzdb -L $(SRC_HEAD)/build/lib -L$(COMMON)/shm -L $(TPLOC)/boost_1_49_0/lib -L $(TPLOC)/libzdb/lib -L $(TPLOC)/apache/lib
```

can someone please advise

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you have another older version of boost installed somewhere, e.g., /usr/include/boost. Your code builds probably with old boost, but not with 1.49.

Also, often there is no need to use `-I.`. Just use `include ""` (with double quotes) that searches the folder of the file that does the include.

Comment: good point, there is another boost set of includes within usr/include - but why does it complain when i force it to look within the path specified above?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the code. Post a minimal complete code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: this is the boost call i make within the code       m_bids = new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create,
                                             "test",
                                             size, 0, allow_all);

Comment: trouble is when i do something similar in another makefile it works perfectly fine so i can't get my head around why it works in one makefile and not the other

Comment: @godzilla, post minimal complete makefiles that produce the behavior, and we'll have a chance of solving the mystery.

Comment: i have removed the /usr/include/ because i needed to clear out some files hoping they would reappear after doing a ./b2 install but they did not, how do i get them back?

Comment: If you're using Fedora or Red Hat do `sudo yum reinstall boost-devel`.